# Searching for a specific string using JavaScript and greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, search, greasemonkey

I have been trying to implement the following and have gathered this little piece of code so far.

To Do :

1. Search for the word "Block" and "Own" if both are present then thrown an alert box "saying both are found"
2. If only "Block" is found then throw an alert box "Only block is found"
3. If only "own" is found along with the word "Cool" then throw alert "own n cool are found "

Also all the alert box should have the the "confirm button and when u click that again it should say "Are you sure you have done that?" with a "ok" button.

The sample code is :

```
if (/Text you are looking for/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
 {
  alert ("Found it!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findAndAlert(element){
  var foundBlock = false,
      foundOwn   = false,
      foundCool  = false;

  if (element.match(/block/i) foundBlock = true;
  if (element.match(/own/i) foundOwn = true;
  if (element.match(/cool/i) foundCool = true; 

  if (foundBlock and foundOwn) alert('Both are found');
  else if (foundBlock && !foundOwn) alert('Only block was found');
  else if ( foundOwn && foundCool) alert('Found own and cool');

}


findAndAlert(document.body.innerHTML)
```

Comment: Will try this and let you know the result